# Check if some elements of array are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I found only a question "If all the elements are equal". It doesn't suit me, I need another thing: Scan the array and take elements that are equal and push them to another array.

Sample Input:

```
arr = [1, 3, 3, 1]
```

Sample Output:

```
group = [[1,1],[3,3]]
```

Here's my code:

```
arr = [1, 3, 3, 1];
group = [];

pickNums = (a,b) => {
... ? group.push([a]) : null

arr.reduce(pickNums);
```

And I don't know what to write instead of "...". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Order the array and then create a new array each times you reach a different value. It's probably the easiest way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group all values in the same group.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 3, 1],
    groups = Array.from(
        array
            .reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, [...(m.get(v) || []), v]), new Map)
            .values()
    );
    
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 2):

Collect the items to a dictionary using [**`Array.reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), then use [**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to convert back to array:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 3, 1];

pickNums = (arr) =>
  Object.values(arr.reduce((r, n) => {
    r[n] = r[n] || [];
  
    r[n].push(n);
  
    return r;
  }, {}));

const groups = pickNums(arr);

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be solved optimally by keeping a counter of similar elements using an Object/Hash.

```
const array = [1, 3, 3, 1];
const elementCounterObject = {};
array.map(element => {
   if (!elementCounterObject[element]) {
       elementCounterObject[element] = 1;
   } else {
       elementCounterObject[element] += 1;
   }
});

console.log(elementCounterObject);   // result: {1: 2, 3: 2}

// converting elementCounterObject to display output as per requirement
const resultingArrayToDisplay = [];

for (let element in elementCounterObject) {
    const numberOfInstances = elementCounterObject[element];
    const elementToNumberOfInstanceArray = new Array(numberOfInstances).fill(parseInt(element));
    resultingArrayToDisplay.push(elementToNumberOfInstanceArray);
};

console.log(resultingArrayToDisplay); // result: [[1,1], [3,3]]
```

I've made this snippet verbose so that you could understand the algorithm behind this. Some fluff could obviously be shaved off to make it concise but I hope this resolves your query

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want :

```
    const arr = [1, 3, 3, 1];
    let groups = [];
    arr.map((item)=>{
          const ar2 = arr.filter( sec => sec == item );
          if (! groups.filter( sec => sec.indexOf(item)>-1).length) {
            groups.push(ar2);
          }
     });

    console.log(groups);
```